# How can I remove a classpath entry from Grails dependencies in GGTS

Tags: grails, ggts

I mistakenly added some jars to Grails dependencies using Java build path dialogue of GGTS.
Now I want to remove them.

But the build path dialogue offers no chance to do so.

Comment: Try Grails Tools -> Refresh dependencies, that is what you'd usually use to bring the Eclipse classpath into line with changed to BuildConfig dependencies.

Comment: doing so leads to a big red '!' on the project. The project cannot be run anymore because of errors. But I don't know, where to find those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the project from eclipse, delete .project and .classpath files. regenerate eclipse files using command grails integrate-with --eclipse and import the project again and you classpath should be good.

Comment: tried but failed with integrate-with --eclipse (error in looking for ant)

Comment: I succeeded in a similiar way: renamed my project to nameX, generated new grails project under the old name and made a simple file import of my renamed nameX project ommitting all grails/eclipse specific artefacts, that I didn't ever touch. It took me just 10 minutes and everything is working fine.